# How to force download a js file using nginx?

Tags: javascript, nginx

I want to force user to download a js/pac file from my server, I' set these code in the **nginx.conf**

```
    server {
    location ~ .*\.(pac|js)$ {
        add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$request_filename";
    }
}
```

or like this

```
    server {
    location /pacfile/ {
        types {
            application/octet-stream js;
        }
    }
}
```

But none of this method works. Why?

Comment: Don't know, but modern browsers support the download attribute on A tags. Try it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve my problem.
I need to set the listen port and server_name;

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    location {...}
}
```

It works now.